# Techniques to clean the topics

Tags: data-mining, dataset, bigdata, data-cleaning

I have set of topics as follows.

"web based", "web-based" -> **with surplus symbols**
"technology","technologies" -> **with singular and plural**
"learned", "learnt", "learning" ->**suffix stripping**

Can you please recommend an accurate tool to perform aforementioned tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For text processing, try using Python and the [NLTK package](http://www.nltk.org/).

For removing surplus symbols, you can use regular expressions. Install package 're' and use the built-in function re.sub to substitute symbols like '-' with empty character.

For suffix stripping, you can either use regular expressions again or use the built-in word stemming functionality in the NLTK package. This [tutorial](https://pythonspot.com/en/nltk-stemming/) should help.